# Trying to send some ETH to a Wallet

Tags: gas, wallets, gas-price, fees

I have an Exodus Wallet with some USDC in it. When I try to exchange them or send them to another wallet, it says that I need to add some ETH to make it possible (0.0043 ETH). I check on Binance and the gas fee for the transaction is 15$ which seems too big. I was wondering if you have any tips on how to deposit a lower amount, without paying too much for the transfer fee?. Thank you and sorry for the bad English!

Answer (score 1):

The transfer fee depends on the used *gas price*. You are free to set any gas price you want, for your transaction, but if you want your transaction processed in a reasonable timeframe you have to set a reasonable gas price for it.

The current gas prices and their respective costs can be seen for example at https://etherscan.io/gastracker . An average ERC20 token transfer costs currently $8.

Centralized exchanges, such as Binance, will include extra fees in the transfers. But you don't really have options if you want to use them - you have to pay their fees.

Comment: Do you know any other exchange where you can buy ETH and they don't charge that much for the gas price?

Comment: That's not possible. Eth transactions cost what they cost - there's no simple way around it for any transaction in the mainnet.